# how to select particular list of tuples, grouped by runs of consecutive numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I want to select a each list of tuples from a group. Each list is grouped by repeats of consecutive numbers.

```
import more_itertools as mit
df=pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2,0,1,2,3], 'b':[2,10,24,56,90,1,3]})
for group in mit.consecutive_groups(zip(df['a'],df['b']),ordering=lambda t:t[0]):
                                    print(list(group))
```

output
    `[(0, 2), (1, 10),(2,24)]`

```
      [(0,56),(1,90),(2,1),(3,3)
```

I tried with groups[0] to access first list in the group, but it did not work.

Comment: So you want to select different tuple elements at the same index (position)?

Comment: yes, that's right. I want to select the first row [(0,2),(1,10),(2,24)] and then second